# How to send a message from my account in ASP.NET C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook

I am creating a web application in [ASP.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET) which displays **all the walls** of the current user using the Facebook API.

He/she can post on his/her wall and get **all messages** of him/her.

Now I also want to send a message to my friend. So how is it possible using the Facebook API?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Send button](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/494/).

#### How to add the send button

The *Send* button can be easily added to existing *Like* buttons or as a standalone feature. Developers currently using the XFBML *Like* button can include the `send="true"` attribute in their *Like* button code to generate a combined button, and those using an iFrame version of the *Like* button will need to upgrade to XFBML to display a *Send* button. The following code will generate a combined *Like* and *Send* button:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
<fb:like href="example.com" show_faces="true" width="450" send="true">
</fb:like>
```

Developers can add a standalone *Send* button with the following code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
<fb:send href="example.com"></fb:send>
```